# Apple device management

Tags: macos, administration

Not sure if this has been answered but I cannot find anything via the search. The whole company (10 people) use Apple devices but aren't all in the same office. Are there any tools that I can use to administer (updates, password policy, asset register) all these devices?

I was pretty sure osx server used to do this but I'm not sure if Apple are still maintaining it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The terms you're looking for are Mobile Device Management (MDM) or Enterprise Mobility Management (EMM)

There are many vendors.  Security.SE isn't a vendor recommendation site, but one option is Cisco's Meraki System Manager - they are free for under 100 devices and can handle a mix of iOS, Windows, Android, MacOS.  Disclaimer : I have no relationship with Cisco other than using their services/products.